# DoesUserHavePermissions returns true but user has no permissions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I have used following code to check if a user has "Read" Permission Levels on Root Web of a site

```
if (site.RootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.ViewPages))
 {
    render root web url;                            
 }
 else
 {
    render public url
 }
```

but it renders root web url för current user without having permissions att all. and when he clicks on the url he gets access denied .... error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try it using `SPBasePermissions.Open` instead of `SPBasePermissions.ViewPages`. If you have anonymous authentication enabled, that may be the reason for this.

Here is a description of all of the options: [SPBasePermissions Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, There is no anonymous policy on Web Application level. and I have changed to SPBasePermissions.Open but still it returns true.

Comment: I have created a Content Database for each Site Collection. Can it be the reason that DoesUserHavePermissions returns true always?

Comment: I found what was the problem I had used RunWithElevatedPrivileges which used system user. I solved it like this RootWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(currentUser.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.Open)